# Android espresso compare strings on the screen with string from assets

Tags: android, file, assert, android-espresso

I would like to compare content of .txt file that i have in my assets folder with some text on the screen.

Usually when I assert text on the screen I use:
onView(withId(R.id.someId)).check(matches(withText("String")));

is ther any easy way so i can assert it from file?

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want to shorten your assertions and actions when using Expresso, check this library: https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista (disclaimer: I'm a contributor).

It contains a set of quick actions and assertions that make the tests much more readable.

Comment: Very nice work Sergi! Also, fantastic stuff on data binding a while back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code to read text from text file.

```
 StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
InputStream json=getAssets().open("book/contents.json");
BufferedReader in=
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"));
String str;

while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
  buf.append(str);
}

in.close();
```

now compare your string from assets to you screen text.

```
buf.toString().equals("your text here");
```